# How to recover windows from an LVM encrypted ubuntu install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, lvm

I was trying out ubuntu 14.04 and I chose the option of using a LVM encrytion, Now I cnat load windows or even access them from ubuntu, I have looked all over the internet for tutorials but none of them are delivering what I want, I just want to recover my precious files in windows 8(which were all in one partition C 4.95GB Drive).
from what I get I need to decrypt that disk then try to recober grub, please assist, any links or directions to do thus will greatly be appreciated, Did I loose my data since when I boot from an ubuntu live disk that it have 459 GB free, yet my files were so many, I only had. 20GB free, im not sure because it said it would not encrypt files outside ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any windows DVD ,boot it,then go to command prompt,then type commands 
`bootrec /fixmbr` 
this will reset your MBR,and you will able to boot from windows 8 :)
your ubuntu partition will remain safe,later you can add a entry from [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) boot menu tool :)
If not working,then comment!

Comment: Thanks, let me do that as soon as possible will let you know

Comment: @thageekboy did you try this?

Comment: Yeah i did,but it was beyond the problem, the Ubuntu had encrypted my whole disk so decrypting it meant loosing all my data.. Thanksthough